# How does postman app set request body for a GET request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4, postman

When I was trying in browser to send a GET request with data from bootstrap datatable ajax to a C# MVC controller method, not all the data that was send was mapped to the model object. Some properties in the model object still remained with null/default value.

I verified the property names and no issues in that. But when I did the same thing in postman app the data was successfully bound to the model object.

Two things that I noted in the postman app is that:

1. The request data is not send in the query string parameter rather in
   the request body with still the method type as **GET** (I don't know
   how that is possible), but in browser as usual the data was URL
   encoded and was sent as query string parameter.
2. In post man app the request headers also contains "Content-Type"
       header with "application/json" as value.

So I also tried with "Content-Type" header with "application/json" but still no use the data was not bound.

Finally I chose the common way, I just set the "Content-Type" header with "application/json", stringified the data with JSON.stringify and I set the type as "POST" and it successfully got mapped.

What I got struggling is, how does the postman app alone can send a GET request like that with data in the request body.

If anyone has idea about this please tell me that would help me to have an idea about the HTTP requests.

1.) PostMan - GET Request Format
[image: PostMan - GET Request Format]

2.) PostMan - Get Request Network Data
[image: PostMan - Get Request Network Data]

3.) PostMan - Get Request Network Data - Raw Format
[image: PostMan - Get Request Network Data - Raw Format]

4.) Backend - Contoller Received Data
[image: Backend - Contoller Received Data]

1.) Browser - GET Request Format
[image: Browser - GET Request Format]

2.) Browser - Query String Parameters
[image: Browser - Query String Parameters]

3.) Backend - Contoller Received Data
[image: Backend - Contoller Received Data]

Comment: Can you show your code and an image of how you have Postman set up?

Comment: @DannyDainton, I've added the images, please take a look on it